Using rtc-rv3028 device affects boot process
I'm using LS1028a-rdb board and I'm facing a problem with my RTC devices.
The board is equipped with NXP pcf2129 and Microcrystal RV3028 (added by our electronics) RTC clocks.
Sometimes when RV3028 is enabled in the device tree and the driver is loaded at boot, the boot process hangs (I'm not able to reach the console) and it prints the following logs to the console:
[  188.940580] udevd[205]: worker [212] /devices/platform/f080000.display timeout; kill it
[  188.948683] udevd[205]: seq 2486 '/devices/platform/f080000.display' killed
[  190.612231] udevd[211]: timeout '/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh'
[  190.617943] udevd[211]: slow: '/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh' [364]
[  190.629844] udevd[208]: timeout '/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh'
[  190.629845] udevd[215]: timeout '/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh'
[  190.629865] udevd[215]: slow: '/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh' [398]
[  190.635555] udevd[208]: slow: '/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh' [406]
[  191.625018] udevd[211]: timeout: killing '/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh' [364]
[  191.632042] udevd[211]: slow: '/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh' [364]
[  194.657432] udevd[205]: worker [209] /devices/platform/soc/2000000.i2c/i2c-0/i2c-8/8-0052 timeout; kill it
[  194.667153] udevd[205]: seq 2576 '/devices/platform/soc/2000000.i2c/i2c-0/i2c-8/8-0052' killed

As you can see last entry refers to RTC RV-3028 which is connected I2C bus on address 0x52. The device itself seems to be working fine (it was tested by electronic guys), as sometimes when everything boots correctly (or when instead of loading rtc-rv3028 module at boot time I load it once I get the console) I'm able to operate on this device, I can read / write time and so on.
There is no address conflict between other devices connected to I2C. I can say even more - the first RTC is connected to completely different I2C bus.
I'm running out of ideas on how to debug it. Disabling rtc-rv3028 driver from being loaded, either through status "disabled" in device-tree or blacklisting in modeprobe solves the problem, but obviously it prevents me from using this device...
Any idea how to debug it? Or what could be the source of the problem?
Linux Kernel version 5.15
I enabled some ftrace logs, it seems that something is being locked...
[   11.500634] i2c_result: i2c-0 n=1 ret=1
[   11.507360] i2c_write: i2c-0 #0 a=00a f=0000 l=4 [00-32-50-00]
[   11.513920] i2c_result: i2c-0 n=1 ret=1
[   11.517772] i2c_result: i2c-2 n=1 ret=1
[   11.521636] i2c_write: i2c-8 #0 a=052 f=0000 l=1 [0e]
[   11.526726] i2c_read: i2c-8 #1 a=052 f=0001 l=1
[   11.531281] i2c_write: i2c-0 #0 a=077 f=0000 l=1 [0f]
[   11.536748] i2c_result: i2c-0 n=1 ret=1
[   11.540600] i2c_write: i2c-0 #0 a=052 f=0000 l=1 [0e]
[   11.545679] i2c_read: i2c-0 #1 a=052 f=0001 l=1
[   11.550824] i2c_reply: i2c-0 #1 a=052 f=0001 l=1 [11]
[   11.555906] i2c_result: i2c-0 n=2 ret=2
[   11.559755] i2c_reply: i2c-8 #1 a=052 f=0001 l=1 [11]
[   11.564835] i2c_result: i2c-8 n=2 ret=2
[   11.568700] i2c_write: i2c-2 #0 a=00a f=0000 l=4 [00-34-00-00]
[   11.574561] i2c_write: i2c-0 #0 a=077 f=0000 l=1 [09]
[   68.574166] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
[   71.582351] udevd[205]: worker [213] /devices/platform/soc/2000000.i2c/i2c-0/i2c-8/8-0052 is taking a long time
[   71.592562] udevd[205]: worker [209] /devices/platform/soc/2000000.i2c/i2c-0/i2c-2/2-000a is taking a long time


1. Check, if the problem appears on the latest vanilla (it might answer the question if it's a driver bug). 2. Check systemd, udev, etc documentation if the system tries to setup your RTC as a clock source at boot time. If you have it as a second RTC, it might be that the kernel loops beetwen them and constantily "updates" the system time, which makes user space behave badly. 3. Use initcall_debug ignore_loglevel in the kernel command line to see more. From what you posted it looks like a result and not a cause.

I disabled all other RTCs, I used mainline rtc-rv3028 with no result, I replaced rv3028 hardware. It seems that something is being locked and not released...
